# php session doesn't work

Tags: php, session, authentication

How it should work:
Index.php is the secured page. It includes check.php, which checks if you have a session = good. If it hasn't, you're not logged in -> log off, remove session. But it doesn't work, it always logs off, like I didn't log in...

**index.php**

```
include ‘check.php’;
echo "logged in";
```

**check.php**

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION[‘login’] != ‘good’) {
unset($_SESSION[‘login’]);
unset($_SESSION[‘name’]);
header(‘Location: login.php?logoff’);
exit();
}
```

**Login.php**

```
if(isset($_POST[‘login’])) {
$gb = array();
$gb[‘user1’] = ‘pass1’;
$gb[‘user2’] = ‘pass2’;
if(isset($gb[$_POST[‘username’]]) && $gb[$_POST[‘username’]] == $_POST[‘password’])
{ 
$_SESSION[‘login’] = ‘good’;
$_SESSION[‘name’] = $_POST[‘name’];

header("Location: index.php");
} else {

header("Location: login.php?wrongpass");

}

} else { ?>
Login Form
<?php } ?>
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Does `login.php` contain `session_start();`?

Comment: your single quotes marks don't look right, is that a copy/paste issue or are they how you've got them set, `‘` and `’` should be `'` or `"`

Comment: Your missing `session_start();` when your login statement is true. if thats not there, php will not recognize it as a session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should verify you started the session in login.php.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have session_start() at the top of all the pages, you havent shown the session start for your login page.

(Thanks to Danny for proving I cant type)

Comment: Ha i thought as much.. couldn't edit it myself though - thought i'd best add it under in-case OP tried to copy/paste

Answer (score 2):

Put `session_start();` in all the pages

Comment: Or do this in php.ini: session.auto_start On

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have `register_globals` is On in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

First check on the pages you want to use session variables session is start or not and if session is not stat then start it.

and this is the very first line in the php file.

Code for the session checking is :

```
if(!session_id())
{
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($count==1){
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $UserName;
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $password;
    UpdateOnlineChecker($Session);
    header( "Location: http://". strip_tags( $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] ) ."/newHolo/" );
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Look at my code. It checks if the statement is true (for me, if there is one row with a query statement i execute). Then i start a session and basically Ill define global session variables, sned out a query to my database to update the session and then refer through.

you are missing a session_start(); in your if true block.

Comment: Well, not in my true block but just in the page (can be on the top too). But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use one for action document such as index.php there is code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
   // login
   header('Location: (here is some page)');
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']){
  // @todo some action
} else {
  require_once('login.php');
}

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
   unset($_SESSION['user']);
   header('Location: (here is some page)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is header:

```
('location:------.php);
```

Your hosting server doesn't run this.
You can use this:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='-----.php'</script>";
```